# How to change the properties ofthe button at a Cell in a DataGridViewButton ? - c#

Tags: c#

How to change the properties ofthe button at a Cell in a DataGridViewButton?
this my code - I get error code -...us read only
(DataGridViewButtonCell)MyDGV.Rows[i].Cells[3].Visible= true;

Comment: Do you need to change this property at grid event or out of grid events?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the control first and cast it to button then get its attribute

```
Button btn = (Button)MyDGV.items.FindControl("ButtonName");
btn.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I have a Cell that full with Buttons - to the buttons don't define a specific name